# Xilinx DSP48 Single Slice 18x18 Complex multiplier

Tags: verilog, programming, xilinx, dsp

I am writing a verilog code for 18x18 complex multiplier using DSP48 single slice implementation in Vertex 4. Here is my code

```
module SS_CM_18x18(Areal,Aimag,Breal,Bimag,Clk,Rst,Preal,Pimag);
input Clk,Rst;
input [17:0]Areal,Aimag,Breal,Bimag;
output [47:0]Preal,Pimag;

reg [47:0]Preal,Pimag;
reg [17:0]Areal_Reg,Aimag_Reg,Breal_Reg,Bimag_Reg;
wire [17:0]Areal_Wire,Aimag_Wire,Breal_Wire,Bimag_Wire;
reg [17:0]I,Q;
wire [47:0]POut;
reg [47:0]POut_Reg1;
reg [1:0]Count;
reg [6:0]OPMODE;
reg Subtract;

always @(posedge Clk or posedge Rst)
    begin
        if (Rst)
            Count<=2'b11;
        else if (Count<2'b11)
            Count<=Count+1;
        else
            Count<=2'b0;
    end

always @(posedge Clk or posedge Rst)
    begin
        if (Rst)
            begin
                Areal_Reg<=18'b0;
                Aimag_Reg<=18'b0;
                Breal_Reg<=18'b0;
                Aimag_Reg<=18'b0;
            end
        else if(Count==2'b00)
            begin
                Areal_Reg<=Areal;
                Aimag_Reg<=Aimag;
                Breal_Reg<=Breal;
                Aimag_Reg<=Bimag;
            end
        else
            begin
                Areal_Reg<=Areal_Reg;
                Aimag_Reg<=Aimag_Reg;
                Breal_Reg<=Breal_Reg;
                Aimag_Reg<=Bimag_Reg;
            end
    end

assign Areal_Wire=Areal_Reg;
assign Aimag_Wire=Aimag_Reg;
assign Breal_Wire=Breal_Reg;
assign Bimag_Wire=Bimag_Reg;

always @(posedge Clk or posedge Rst)
    begin
        if (Rst)
            begin
                I<=18'b0;
                Q<=18'b0;
                OPMODE<=7'b0;
                Subtract<=1'b0;
            end
        else
            begin
                case(Count)
                    2'd0:   begin
                                I<=Areal_Wire;
                                Q<=Breal_Wire;
                                OPMODE<=7'b0000101;
                                Subtract<=1'b0;
                            end
                    2'd1:   begin
                                I<=Aimag_Wire;
                                Q<=Bimag_Wire;
                                OPMODE<=7'b0100101;
                                Subtract<=1'b1;
                            end
                    2'd2:   begin
                                I<=Areal_Wire;
                                Q<=Bimag_Wire;
                                OPMODE<=7'b0000101;
                                Subtract<=1'b0;
                            end
                    2'd3:   begin
                                I<=Aimag_Wire;
                                Q<=Breal_Wire;
                                OPMODE<=7'b0100101;
                                Subtract<=1'b0;
                            end
                endcase
            end
    end

// DSP48: DSP Function Block
//        Virtex-4
// Xilinx HDL Language Template, version 13.4

DSP48 #(
  .AREG(0),           // Number of pipeline registers on the A input, 0, 1 or 2
  .BREG(0),           // Number of pipeline registers on the B input, 0, 1 or 2
  .B_INPUT("DIRECT"), // B input DIRECT from fabric or CASCADE from another DSP48
  .CARRYINREG(0),     // Number of pipeline registers for the CARRYIN input, 0 or 1
  .CARRYINSELREG(0),  // Number of pipeline registers for the CARRYINSEL, 0 or 1
  .CREG(0),           // Number of pipeline registers on the C input, 0 or 1
  .LEGACY_MODE("MULT18X18"), // Backward compatibility, NONE, MULT18X18 or MULT18X18S
  .MREG(0),           // Number of multiplier pipeline registers, 0 or 1
  .OPMODEREG(0),      // Number of pipeline regsiters on OPMODE input, 0 or 1
  .PREG(1),           // Number of pipeline registers on the P output, 0 or 1
  .SUBTRACTREG(0)     // Number of pipeline registers on the SUBTRACT input, 0 or 1
   )  
 DSP48_inst1 (
      .BCOUT(),  // 18-bit B cascade output
      .P(POut),          // 48-bit product output
      .PCOUT(),  // 48-bit cascade output
      .A(I),          // 18-bit A data input
      .B(Q),          // 18-bit B data input
      .BCIN(18'd0),    // 18-bit B cascade input
      .C(48'd0),          // 48-bit cascade input
      .CARRYIN(1'd0), // Carry input signal
      .CARRYINSEL(2'd0), // 2-bit carry input select
      .CEA(1'b1),      // A data clock enable input
      .CEB(1'b1),      // B data clock enable input
      .CEC(1'b0),      // C data clock enable input
      .CECARRYIN(1'b0), // CARRYIN clock enable input
      .CECINSUB(1'b1), // CINSUB clock enable input
      .CECTRL(1'b0), // Clock Enable input for CTRL regsiters
      .CEM(1'b1),       // Clock Enable input for multiplier regsiters
      .CEP(1'b1),       // Clock Enable input for P regsiters
      .CLK(Clk),       // Clock input
      .OPMODE(OPMODE), // 7-bit operation mode input
      .PCIN(48'b0),     // 48-bit PCIN input 
      .RSTA(Rst),     // Reset input for A pipeline registers
      .RSTB(Rst),     // Reset input for B pipeline registers
      .RSTC(Rst),     // Reset input for C pipeline registers
      .RSTCARRYIN(Rst), // Reset input for CARRYIN registers
      .RSTCTRL(Rst), // Reset input for CTRL registers
      .RSTM(Rst), // Reset input for multiplier registers
      .RSTP(Rst), // Reset input for P pipeline registers
      .SUBTRACT(Subtract) // SUBTRACT input
   );

   // End of DSP48_inst instantiation

always @(posedge Clk or posedge Rst)
    begin
        if (Rst)
            POut_Reg1<=48'b0;
        else
            POut_Reg1<=POut;
    end
always @(posedge Clk or posedge Rst)
    begin
        if (Rst)
            begin
                Preal<=48'b0;
                Pimag<=48'b0;
            end
        else if (Count==2'b00)
            Preal<=POut_Reg1;
        else if (Count==2'd10)
            Pimag<=POut_Reg1;
        else
            begin
                Preal<=Preal;
                Pimag<=Pimag;
            end
    end

endmodule
```

The Test bench for the program is

```
module Test_SS_CM_18x18;

    // Inputs
reg [17:0] Areal;
reg [17:0] Aimag;
reg [17:0] Breal;
reg [17:0] Bimag;
reg Clk;
reg Rst;

// Outputs
wire [47:0] Preal;
wire [47:0] Pimag;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
SS_CM_18x18 uut1 (
    .Areal(Areal), 
    .Aimag(Aimag), 
    .Breal(Breal), 
    .Bimag(Bimag), 
    .Clk(Clk), 
    .Rst(Rst), 
    .Preal(Preal), 
    .Pimag(Pimag)
);

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    Areal = 0;
    Aimag = 0;
    Breal = 0;
    Bimag = 0;
    Clk = 0;
    Rst = 0;

    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #105;
   Rst=1;
    #10 Rst = 0;         
    // Add stimulus here
    Areal=18'd1;
    Aimag=18'd1;
    Breal=18'd1;
    Bimag=18'd1;
end
always #5 Clk=~Clk;      
endmodule
```

I am not getting the correct output. Can anybody tell me where i am making a mistake in code/concept
The output goes to 0 after 3 clk cycles & then 3 clk cycles after Reset it goes to high impedance state

Comment: It might be worth adding an example of one set of inputs and the output you get. That might give an added clue to which part is wrong.

Comment: @PeterJ Edited with test bench & output

Comment: There's no reason anything should be going high-impedance in this design. Is it merely going "unknown"? Can you show us the actual simulator waveforms?

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see with your code is that you load I and Q on the first cycle (`Count == 0`) from the pipeline registers instead of directly from the inputs. Since the pipline registers themselves are being loaded on that same clock, the multiplier isn't going to get what you expect.

Here's a version of your module with that problem fixed, and a lot of other extraneous cruft removed:

```
module SS_CM_18x18 (
  Areal,
  Aimag,
  Breal,
  Bimag,
  Clk,
  Rst,
  Preal,
  Pimag
);

  input         Clk, Rst;
  input  [17:0] Areal, Aimag, Breal, Bimag;
  output [47:0] Preal, Pimag;

  reg    [47:0] Preal, Pimag;
  reg    [17:0] Areal_Reg, Aimag_Reg, Breal_Reg, Bimag_Reg;
  reg    [17:0] I, Q;
  wire   [47:0] POut;
  reg    [47:0] POut_Reg1;
  reg     [1:0] Count;
  reg     [6:0] OPMODE;
  reg           Subtract;

  always @(posedge Clk or posedge Rst) begin
    if (Rst) Count <= 2'b11;
    else if (Count<2'b11) Count <= Count+1;
    else Count <= 2'b0;
  end

  always @(posedge Clk or posedge Rst) begin
    if (Rst) begin
      Areal_Reg <= 18'b0;
      Aimag_Reg <= 18'b0;
      Breal_Reg <= 18'b0;
      Aimag_Reg <= 18'b0;
    end else if (Count == 2'b00) begin
      Areal_Reg <= Areal;
      Aimag_Reg <= Aimag;
      Breal_Reg <= Breal;
      Aimag_Reg <= Bimag;
    end
  end

  always @(posedge Clk or posedge Rst) begin
    if (Rst) begin
      I <= 18'b0;
      Q <= 18'b0;
      OPMODE <= 7'b0;
      Subtract <= 1'b0;
    end else begin
      case (Count)

        2'd0: begin
          I <= Areal;           // direct from input
          Q <= Breal;           // direct from input
          OPMODE <= 7'b0000101;
          Subtract <= 1'b0;
        end

        2'd1: begin
          I <= Aimag_Reg;
          Q <= Bimag_Reg;
          OPMODE <= 7'b0100101;
          Subtract <= 1'b1;
        end

        2'd2: begin
          I <= Areal_Reg;
          Q <= Bimag_Reg;
          OPMODE <= 7'b0000101;
          Subtract <= 1'b0;
        end

        2'd3: begin
          I <= Aimag_Reg;
          Q <= Breal_Reg;
          OPMODE <= 7'b0100101;
          Subtract <= 1'b0;
        end
      endcase
    end
  end

  // DSP48: DSP Function Block
  //        Virtex-4
  // Xilinx HDL Language Template, version 13.4

  DSP48 #(
    .AREG(0),           // Number of pipeline registers on the A input, 0, 1 or 2
    .BREG(0),           // Number of pipeline registers on the B input, 0, 1 or 2
    .B_INPUT("DIRECT"), // B input DIRECT from fabric or CASCADE from another DSP48
    .CARRYINREG(0),     // Number of pipeline registers for the CARRYIN input, 0 or 1
    .CARRYINSELREG(0),  // Number of pipeline registers for the CARRYINSEL, 0 or 1
    .CREG(0),           // Number of pipeline registers on the C input, 0 or 1
    .LEGACY_MODE("MULT18X18"), // Backward compatibility, NONE, MULT18X18 or MULT18X18S
    .MREG(0),           // Number of multiplier pipeline registers, 0 or 1
    .OPMODEREG(0),      // Number of pipeline regsiters on OPMODE input, 0 or 1
    .PREG(1),           // Number of pipeline registers on the P output, 0 or 1
    .SUBTRACTREG(0)     // Number of pipeline registers on the SUBTRACT input, 0 or 1
  ) DSP48_inst1 (
    .BCOUT      (),             // 18-bit B cascade output
    .P          (POut),         // 48-bit product output
    .PCOUT      (),             // 48-bit cascade output
    .A          (I),            // 18-bit A data input
    .B          (Q),            // 18-bit B data input
    .BCIN       (18'd0),        // 18-bit B cascade input
    .C          (48'd0),        // 48-bit cascade input
    .CARRYIN    (1'd0),         // Carry input signal
    .CARRYINSEL (2'd0),         // 2-bit carry input select
    .CEA        (1'b1),         // A data clock enable input
    .CEB        (1'b1),         // B data clock enable input
    .CEC        (1'b0),         // C data clock enable input
    .CECARRYIN  (1'b0),         // CARRYIN clock enable input
    .CECINSUB   (1'b1),         // CINSUB clock enable input
    .CECTRL     (1'b1),         // Clock Enable input for CTRL regsiters
    .CEM        (1'b1),         // Clock Enable input for multiplier regsiters
    .CEP        (1'b1),         // Clock Enable input for P regsiters
    .CLK        (Clk),          // Clock input
    .OPMODE     (OPMODE),       // 7-bit operation mode input
    .PCIN       (48'b0),        // 48-bit PCIN input
    .RSTA       (Rst),          // Reset input for A pipeline registers
    .RSTB       (Rst),          // Reset input for B pipeline registers
    .RSTC       (Rst),          // Reset input for C pipeline registers
    .RSTCARRYIN (Rst),          // Reset input for CARRYIN registers
    .RSTCTRL    (Rst),          // Reset input for CTRL registers
    .RSTM       (Rst),          // Reset input for multiplier registers
    .RSTP       (Rst),          // Reset input for P pipeline registers
    .SUBTRACT   (Subtract)      // SUBTRACT input
  );

  // End of DSP48_inst instantiation

  always @(posedge Clk or posedge Rst) begin
    if (Rst) POut_Reg1 <= 48'b0;
    else POut_Reg1 <= POut;
  end

  always @(posedge Clk or posedge Rst) begin
    if (Rst) begin
      Preal <= 48'b0;
      Pimag <= 48'b0;
    end else if (Count == 2'b00) Preal <= POut_Reg1;
    else if (Count == 2'd10) Pimag <= POut_Reg1;
  end

endmodule
```

Also, I'm not totally familiar with the details of DPS48, but did you really want to tie CECTRL low? I've changed it to high.